# How to copy a row and insert in same table with a autoincrement field in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have the following table

[image: i have the following table]

here i need to copy the 2nd row and insert it to  exactly at the next row and also 
    insert a value to the detail column as like following table

[image]

what would be the Query to do this assignment

Comment: what you tried so far ? Post your query pls ?

Comment: Didn't you want to insert a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into tablename
Select status,valu,'delivered' as detail from table name where valu='mid120850'
```

I'm assuming the SlNo is an `auto increment`?